# Was Vashti Evil?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, midrash, historical-figures, megillat-esther, evil-resha

Is there any basis within the text of the Megillah itself to lend credence to the common Midrashic theme that Vasti was evil?

Comment: This question is particularly relevant as she has been widely presented as a feminist heroine (!) [e.g. here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vashti#As_a_feminist_icon)

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Good point about the period the Gemara itself raises the issue of perception of the Megillah by contemporary Persians claiming that he rabbis of the period raised the issue. Nevertheless, the Megillah does present Achashverosh as at best a well meaning incompetent drunk.

Comment: According to the Gemara she is the daughter of Belshazar, the king of the "writing on the wall" story in Daniel. The kingdom was changing hands several times, Darius the Elder lasted just one year as king. That she came from a dodgy line of descent does not of course make her evil but she was not pure either.

Comment: @CashCow Look at Ester's husband, Avraham's father, Rachel and Leah's father, for a couple of exeptions.

Comment: I, too, would love to know the answer to this question. In my learning (Chabad women's) I was taught that she was bad, and I always assumed this was extrapolated from the fact she was disobedient to her husband. But I found this confusing; surely the Chabad women's circle wouldn't rather she danced naked at the party, as asked?!

Comment: Going to award the bounty to @msh210 but would definitely appreciate any more evidence that can be found, whenever...

Answer (score 2):

*Rava* (*Bavli* 12) sees it in 1:9, which says *Vashti* made a party for women in the king's home: he says she must have made it there rather than in her own home because she intended sin [presumably lewd intermingling].

Comment: First of all I understood the OP to mean evil as in wicked to people, not to Hashem. Secondly, where is this clear in the text itself?

Comment: @Yehuda I don't know why you'd read "evil" that way. And if you don't see the implication clearly in the verse, don't worry: _Rava_ did.

Comment: For that price the Amoiroim saw everything in the verse, the OP wanted something stated clearly that didnt need Torah She'Baal Peh. IMO.

Comment: @Yehuda Please reread the question. It seeks a "basis" in the text of Esther "to lend credence to" what _Chazal_ say. It doesn't seek "_maamare Chazal_ paraphrased in the text of Esther".

Comment: You may be right, I suppose the OP can clarify anyway.

Comment: @msh210 was correctly medayek; I didnt want midrashim, but I was open to textual analysis below the surface, although I was hoping for something in the style of the pashtanim lik Ibn Ezra. In this case it says she made the party in "beis hamalchus" (IIRC) which isnt that clear as being the "men zone" as opposed to some part of the palace grounds. The Gemara says she souldve made it in "Beis Hanashim" but that is making the assumption that the place we find mentioned as housing girls for Achashverosh wouldvr been an appropriate place for a party. Maybe beis hanashim want a part of the palace...

Comment: @msh210 And Vashti wasnt going to leave the palace. Maybe she did make it in the beis hanashim and and that was included in beis hamalchus. thus we dont seem to have to much textual support.

Comment: Going to award the bounty to @msh210 but would definitely appreciate any more evidence that can be found, whenever...

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on the sources: in the Megillah she does nothing wrong, while some midrash describe her as vain, lustful and arrogant (cheating on her husband, stripping her handmaids, etc...); but, even in the latter case, she appears rather mischievous than really evil.

Comment: In what world is cheating on her husband and abusing her servants not evil???

Comment: In the civilized world, transgressions are not all the same: cheating on a husband or lusting after handmaids is not equal to plan a genocide.
"Evil" is someone who primarily aims to harm others; someone who is unable to control his/her lust is rather a dissolute.
Vashti aimed primarily to her own pleasure, we can call her "dissolute" but certainly not evil like Aman who planned to exterminate an entire people...